# Postman returns status 200 OK, but JMeter gives 'Connection timed out'

Tags: jmeter, get, request, postman

I will try to provide as much as information as I can remember and can share due to sensitive data.

**Postman:**

I have an GET request which response gives me  auth token and I pass that token to rest of the requests. I get STATUS: 200 OK every time. The GET request has some header configuration - some default ones and some specific to call i am sending. Postman proxy settings uses system default one.

**JMeter**

So in JMeter I have a *Thread Group*, and in that thread group is a *HTTP Request ( GET )*, and for that HTTP Request I added *HTTP Header Manager* where I copied all headers that are in Postman. Also I've tried to set Timeouts(milliseconds) in Advanced settings for HTTP Request. Also I've tried setting proxy for JMeter from command prompt but still no hope. HTTP Request uses ***https*** protocol.

The errors I am getting in JMeter ( via View Results Tree ) are:

"Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to "cant share - confidential link" Connection timed out: connect"

Does anyone have some ideas what could've I set wrong ( I always assume that it is my fault in the first place )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If JMeter cannot connect to the server and Postman can most probably it means that networking configuration is not correct.

   So check your [Postman proxy settings](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/) and make sure that JMeter is [using the same proxy host and port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).
2. Another possible reason is that you missed something during "copying" of your Postman configuration so you can try [recording your Postman script execution via JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling), but JMeter needs to be able to reach the application you're testing so if it assumes proxy setup - ensure that point 1 is done.

Comment: I’ve just fixed this morrning issue. It was a proxy issue. The JMeter wasn’t using the same ( if any at all ) proxy as Postman.